# Loop of a function for several files

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I am new programming in python and I would like to know a method for the next issue.

I have a python Script that collects data from experiments and saves them in a .csv format organized by columns.

Making use of the function below, I am able to create a folder per day (DATE-folder) that the experiment is carried out, and subfolders (Run_(j)) everytime that I run the script, acquaring 5 files in the subfolder.

```
DATE      = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), DATE)):
    os.makedirs(DATE)

def move_files():
    os.chdir(DATE)
    for j in range(1, 101):
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Run_'+ str(j))):
            break
    os.makedirs('Run_' + str(j))
    src_files = os.listdir(os.curdir)
    for file_name in src_files:
        full_file_name = os.path.join(os.curdir, file_name)
        if os.path.isfile(full_file_name):
            shutil.move(full_file_name, 'Run_' + str(j))
```

As an example I get something like that:

```
DATE/ Run_1 / File_sweep_1.csv,File_sweep_2.csv,File_sweep_3.csv,File_sweep_4.csv,File_sweep_5.csv
      Run_2 / File_sweep_1.csv,File_sweep_2.csv,File_sweep_3.csv,File_sweep_4.csv,File_sweep_5.csv
        .
        .
      Run_j / File_sweep_1.csv,File_sweep_2.csv,File_sweep_3.csv,File_sweep_4.csv,File_sweep_5.csv
```

Now, I want to use another script to analize the data from the experiment avoiding to change the path of the directory that the files are, let's say doing them like in loop somehow. Until the moment I have used this:

```
os.chdir('MainPath/2020-02-12/Run_1')
print('You are working on this directory:\n', os.getcwd(), '\n')
print('The files in the directory are:\n',os.listdir(), '\n')

data = pd.read_csv("File_sweep_1.csv")
```

Then I apply my function and get my results, however I want to avoid to change manually the File_sweep_1.csv, File_sweep_2.csv... File_sweep_5.csv.

Basically what I want Is to run my function for analayzing and that it is applied to every file in every subfolder Run_(j) inside the DATE-folder. The DATE-folder is not an inconvenient, because i can change it manually when needed.

Do you have any tips about how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's an efficient way to load all file in o specific folder

```
import os 

def load_data():
    folder = 'MainPath/2020-02-12/Run_1'
    for root, _, files in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".csv"):
                yield pd.read_csv(root + os.path.sep + file)

for data in load_data():
    # do something with the data
```

The python method walk() generates the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down

Comment: thnak you for your answer. Following these steps i am able to see the files in every directory. However, how can import the data from there to make use of my fucntions?

making use of the yield doesnt allow me to do something like:
yield `data = pd.read_csv(root + os.path.sep + file)`